# How to Display Content from Search URLs on Permanent URLs in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, search, urls

The search link for a WordPress website looks something like this: https://example.org/?s=seo or https://example.org/?s=blogging.

For certain specific pages, I prefer to use permanent links. For example: https://example.org/topic/seo or https://example.org/topic/blogging.

Is it possible to display the same content as what's on https://example.org/?s=seo and https://example.org/?s=blogging for these URLs?"

**I prefer if the topic is a custom post type so I can manage SEO titles, meta desc, some additional content and other things.**

Comment: It is certainly possible to use the WordPress rewriting API to rewrite `https://example.org/topic/<keyword>` to `https://example.org/?s=<keyword>`. But if you wanted the keyword be created as a post, then you should have a whitelist of topics/keywords; so, are they just going to be in one word (e.g. `seo`), or will there also be those in two or more words (e.g. `foo-seo`)? Also, what tool/plugin would you use to manage the SEO titles? And have you already tried with any code and/or approaches - what, if yes?

Comment: @Ranuka Are you willing to generate permanent pages in the WP automatically whenever someone searches for something on the site? So that you may update title, description etc while the page still shows the search results? OR your context is different? Like just add permanent pages for some searches that you already know?

Comment: @AqsaJ. The second one. I know some searches already.

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered a custom post type and have added a custom template for it to your theme, then you could do something like this.

Add a helper function to `functions.php` that creates a custom query to find posts matching the topic slug. *Using a helper keeps the template file a little cleaner.*

```
// functions.php
function wpse_418573_search_posts_by_topic(string $topic, int $paged = 1) : WP_Query {
    return new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
        's' => $topic,
        'paged' => $paged,
    ]);
}
```

In your custom template have the default Loop handle the rendering of the CPT's content. Execute the search query by passing the CPT's slug as a parameter and loop the found posts to display the search results.

```
// single-topic.php
<article class="topic">
    <section class="topic__description">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
            <h1 class="topic__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </section>

    <?php
        global $post;
        $search = wpse_418573_search_posts_by_topic($post->post_name, get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ));

        if ($search->have_posts()): ?>
        <section class="topic__search">
            <?php while ( $search->have_posts() ): $search->the_post(); ?>
                <article class="topic__post entry">
                    <h2 class="entry__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </section>
    <?php endif;?>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

My general approach would be to use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action to intercept the search query and then to change that query to suit your needs. It would start like this:

```
function wpse418573_search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search ) 
      {
        DO YOUR THING
      }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse418573_search_filter' );
```

Now you have selected only the search queries, you can limit the scope further, for instance:

```
//  First get the search term
$s = $query->get( 's' );
// If the search query is for a certain keyword remove the search query and substitute a certain page
if ($s == 'blogging') {$query->set( 's' , ''); $query->set( 'page_id' , 37 );}
// You may have to change more depending on other active query filters
```

Things become a bit more complicated it you want to manage the keywords and corresponding page_id's in a post type. In that case you would have to run a separate [query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to retrieve the info from that post type before you can test which search terms to intercept. You probably also want to exclude that post type itself from the search.